# How to capture process output in C?

Tags: c, linux, unix, system, posix

Is there any analog of PHP's system in C?

`man system` says, that `system` return status of the command, but I need the output (like in PHP).

Of course, I can use pipes for this, but is there any standard way?

Comment: I think you want popen('command goes here').  Read your man page on popen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [**popen**](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/popen.html) and related function as:

```
// command to be run.
char *cmd = "date"; 

// open pipe stream.
FILE *fp = popen(cmd,"r");
int ch; 

// error checking.
if(!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error popen with %s\n",cmd);
        exit(1);
}   

// read from the process and print.
while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        putchar(ch);
}

// close the stream.
pclose(fp);
```

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/9BbFa)

Answer (score 2):

If you need the output of the command, you'd use [`popen()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) on Unix (with "r" to indicate that you want to read from the command).

```
FILE *fp = popen("some -convoluted command", "r");
...check for validity...
...read data from command...
pclose(fp);
```