# returning an int from UNIX

Tags: c, unix

I need to find the number of files in a directory with my C program but I am having trouble saving the number. I am using the system command and not having any luck.

```
n = system( " ls | wc -l " ) ;
```

system does not seem to return a number so I am kinda stuck at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: system does return a number. What exactly do you expect to get as a return value in your case?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324114/how-to-capture-process-output-in-c This explains how to capture the output and read from it as if a file.

Comment: the number of files is the output of the command you are running **not** its return value. `system()` returns the return value of the command

Answer (score 3):

you should use the scandir POSIX function.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scandir.html

An example

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dirent **namelist;
int n;
n = scandir(".", &namelist, 0, alphasort);
printf("%d files\n", n);
```

When you are programming C code using Unix functions, POSIX functions are the standard way to do this. You can implement your own `ls` functions in a standard way.

Enjoy!

NOTE: you can define a selector to use in scandir, for example, to get only the non directory results

```
int selector (struct dirent * entry)
{
   return (entry->d_type != 4);
}
```

For more options type, visit: http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=dirent

Then you can scan your directory using your custom selector (and sort method):

```
n = scandir(".", &namelist, selector, alphasort);
```

Comment: In addition, it would be wise to check scandir's return value to determine success/failure as documented by the opengroup link above.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about counting files, then better to do it using C library functions, if possible, like @Arnaldog illustrates.

However, if your question is about retrieving output from executed child processes, `popen(3)`/`pclose(3)` (conforming to POSIX.1-2001) are your friends. The function `popen()` return `FILE` pointer that you can use just like that returned by `fopen()`, just need to remember to close the stream using `pclose()` to avoid resource leak.

Simple illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    FILE * pf = popen("ls | wc -l", "r");
    if (pf == (FILE *) 0) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error with popen - %m\n");
         pclose(pf);
         return -1;
    }
    if (fscanf(pf, "%d", &n) != 1) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected output from pipe...\n");
         pclose(pf);
         return -1;
    }
    printf("Number of files: %d\n", n);
    pclose(pf);
    return 0;
}
```