# How to get the stdout of an exe I have called through my program?

Tags: c, assembly, dos, x86-16, turbo-c

I want to get the output of an executable without creating an extra file.

Is there any way I can read the output using a FILE pointer on the stdout of that exe or is there some more efficient way?

Comment: How have you "called" the program? One way is to us [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture process output in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324114/how-to-capture-process-output-in-c)

Comment: I cannot find `popen()` in TURBO-C's `stdio.h`

Comment: Any luck apart from redirecting the output in another file?

Comment: Pipes are a feature provided by the OS. DOS doesn’t support them. The DOS command line processor supports pipe syntax, but it implements it by using a temporary file.

Comment: @HelloWorld It cannot be done on DOS in a reasonable way.  There are some approaches using custom device drivers and TSRs but I recommend you to stay away from that as it's a deep abyss to fall into.  Use a temporary file.

Comment: Oh..Thanks alot for you help @fuz

Comment: @HelloWorld Save yourself some time and read the list of standard library functions supported by Turbo C.  Anything not on this list has to be implemented by yourself.  For example, if there is nothing about pipes, this means that pipes are not supported.

Comment: I already read it...Hmm..Will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why in the first place do you use such an ancient system and such an ancient compiler?

Comment: @thebusybee According to [this petition](https://www.change.org/p/update-computer-science-syllabus-for-class-xi-and-xii), educational institutions in India use an outdated syllabus that warrants the use of Turbo C++.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Poor Indians, and that explains the bad quality of source code I'm experiencing. I feel so sorry about them. OTOH my job is safe for next 10 years, and then I'll retire.

Comment: @thebusybee It's neither C++17 nor a fancy IDE that makes a good programmer.

Comment: @RuudHelderman That's right! :^D But the sources I mean are plain bad even in K&R-C. The heavily out-dated syllabus is just a sign of the quality-awareness of the responsible persons. And I found that the OP is working on a DOS emulator, so the choice might be sensible. I wonder if my impression is right.

Comment: Not the the outdated syllabus but the emphasis on irrelevant things that leads to that quality of code.

Comment: I'm interfacing DOSBox in such a way that it is accessible easily from the Windows command line.

Comment: Can someone help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351282/is-there-any-way-to-handle-the-incompatibility-error-thrown-by-windows

Comment: @HelloWorld If that is your goal, make sure to say so as early as possible in your question!  Dosbox has all sorts of escape hatches to make interfacing with the rest of the system easier. If I recall correctly, it can even simulate `CON` being a serial console that is connected to stdin/stdout of the Dosbox process.

Comment: However, if you do not state exactly what you are trying to achieve, there is nothing I can do but say “it cannot be done in a reasonable way within the given constraints.”  Thus, whenever you ask a question, be as specific as possible about what exactly your environment is and what exactly you are trying to achieve.  Also, don't fall prey to the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)!  Ask about the problem you try to solve, not a dead-end approach you picked.

Comment: @fuz Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @HelloWorld What shall I elaborate on?